# How to enable VMX?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, intel-haxm

I want to install Intel HAXM 7.6.5. If I do this the setup aborts with this error:

> The system requirements are not satisfied

In the background you can see the `checktool.exe`. This is the output:

```
checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       *  Yes
VMX enabled         -  No
EPT supported       *  Yes
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.18362
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
```

I don't know what the requirements for HAXM are, but it seems that `VMX` is not enabled. How do I enable it?

**Edit:**

I checked the system requirements and they are met (Intel Core i7-8700 with Windows 1903). Now I enabled in the BIOS the following settings:

- Intel(r) Virtualization Technology
- VT-d
- TxT

Through this I was able to install HAXM without problems. Don't know why but I would say I tried that before. Perhaps I missed TxT ... Thanks Ramhound.

Comment: [HAXM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) requirements

Comment: Have you enabled VT-x within your firmware settings?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author indicated that VT-x was actually disabled and once it was enabled their problems were solved.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76767321/7389293

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not enough to just enable VT in the BIOS and disable Hyper-V in windows. You also need to disable Hyper-V in the BIOS. The setup misleadingly lets you think it failed because for some other reason, and that its ok with the fact that "Hyper-V-Disabled: No". What it really wants is "Hyper-V-Disabled: Yes" and not just in the OS, also in the BIOS.

Actually, after alot of twiddling, I just got it to work. Use the Windows Search box to find "Turn Windows Features On or Off"

Within it there are several features (Windows 11) relating to virtualization:

- Guarded Host
- Hyper-V (careful, upon de-/selection not all sub items get de-/selected even though graphic shows otherwise)
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform
- Windows Sandbox
- Windows Subsystem for Linux

So what I did was fully disable the following:

- Hyper-V
- Windows Sandbox
- Windows Hypervisor Platform
- Virtual Machine Platform

I'm not sure which of those were actually necessary to disable (I'm sure this would interfere with any VMWare or VirtualBox installation, which I don't use), but it made it work. To be fair, I had previously also performed actions described here:

https://github.com/intel/haxm/blob/master/docs/manual-windows.md#disabling-hyper-v-on-windows-10

But that alone wasn't enough, so I don't know if it is also a requirement. Also note that The Issues section on HAXM's Github Page, describe why HAXM and Hyper-V are incompatible and why Hyper-V has to be fully disabled. There is also talk about WSL2 being involved with Hyper-V, hence HAXM not installing when WSL2 is enabled. I personally didn't need to disable it though.

More importantly, since Hyper-V is sometimes needed, the following page explains then how to deal with this when you need HAXM too:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-whpx

Comment: There would not be a Hyper-V firmware settings, because the firmware is not concerned with Hyper-V (or any other application of hardware-assisted virtualization).

Comment: “You also need to disable Hyper-V in the BIOS.” - Hyper-V is a feature of Windows.  You are suggesting disabling a ton of helpful Windows features unnecessarily. WSL2 doesn’t require Hyper-V, so those discussions, are invalid or at least inaccurate if they suggest WSL should be disabled. The first inaccurate and completely false statement about disabling Hyper-V in the BIOS is the reason I am downvoting this answer.  If you edit your answer and remove the inaccurate information I will reverse my vote.

Comment: no don't reverse, just get a hobby. Read the part that says: I'm not sure which of those were actually necessary to disable. The issue here has nothing to do with WSL2